# When coming out of sleep mode, the system drive is put into read-only mode?

Tags: suspend, laptop, read-only, mode

I just want to preface this by saying that I'm very new to Linux, so I'm sorry if I don't understand something that should be obvious.

Basically, I run Ubuntu off of a USB drive on my laptop. After I close the laptop and it goes into sleep mode, when I wake it up, the whole USB drive is in read-only. This was a pain the first time it happened because I couldn't save any of my work, and had to restart to fix the problem. What could the cause of this be, and how would I fix it? The next time I can, I'll get the logs and post them here. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not surprised that there is a problem resuming a USB hosted version of Ubuntu when coming out of sleep mode.  The obvious solution would be to install Ubuntu on the Laptop HDD/SDD as either the sole OS or in a dual boot environment.  Depending on your HW, there *MAY* be an option in BIOS to keep the USB port active even in sleep mode.....  and/or setting the hw so that it doesn't sleep when closing the laptop lid.  Or.... just frequently save your work....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out a work-around. I just went into the settings and changed the action for closing the laptop to "do nothing."